# Alternativ for Sigaction

Tags: c++, linux, signals

I have a problem using sigaction in C++ with this class:

```
class SerialHandler{
private:
...
             
    /* Action Handling */
    struct sigaction receive_handler;
    /* Called using the receive_handler*/
    static void receive_function(int status);
    /* Get byte from the Serial Port */
    unsigned char receive_byte();
    /* Buffer for Singalinterrupt on Reciving */
    std::vector<char> in_char_buffer;
    ...
};
```

I really need to use an Interrupt and really need to use a member function (receive_function) on the Interrupt/Sigaction, because I need access to a member variable (vector in_char_buffer). Problem: You can't use member function using sigaction because you have to pass a normal function to the sigaction.sa_handler.

As you can see using a `static` function isn't an alternative either, because you would not be able to get access to the member variable. Also a wrapper would not help. You would access to an new object but not to the specific one.

So is there an alternative that can handle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class SerialHandler;

// A Singleton class
class SerialHandlerManager
{
private:
    SerialHandlerManager() {};

public:
    static SerialHandlerManager* get_instance();
    void register_handler( int signum, int fd, SerialHandler * handler );

private:
    static void dispatch_signal( int signum, siginfo_t * info, void * context );

private:
    static SerialHandlerManager* the_manager;
    vector<SerialHandler *> handler_objects;
};

class SerialHandler
{
private:
    friend class SerialHandlerManager;
    void install_signal_handler( int signum )
    {
        (SerialHandlerManager::get_instance())->register_handler( signum, fd, this );
    }

    void receive_function( int status );

    int fd;     // file descriptor returned from opening the serial port
};

SerialHandlerManager* SerialHandlerManager::the_manager;

SerialHandlerManager* SerialHandlerManager::get_instance()
{
    if( !the_manager )
        the_manager = new SerialHandlerManager;
    return the_manager;
}

void SerialHandlerManager::register_handler( int signum, int fd, SerialHandler * handler )
{
    struct sigaction act;

    memset( &act, 0, sizeof(struct sigaction));

    act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    act.sa_sigaction = SerialHandlerManager::dispatch_signal;

    handler_objects[fd] = handler;
    sigaction( signum, &act, NULL );

}

void SerialHandlerManager::dispatch_signal( int signum, siginfo_t * info, void * context )
{
    (get_instance()->handler_objects[info->si_fd])->receive_function( signum );
}
```

Of course you can use a map to link file descriptors to objects. This is by no means to be comprehensive (or bulletproof) but just a quick thought I had whilst reading your question.

Good luck

Alwin

Comment: Thank you very much. That nearly did the job. There was one little bug in your solution. I had to `resize()` the `handler_objects` before you put in the `handler`. Now the receive_function is executed.
Sadly there is another issue using the 'siginfo_t->si_fd'. Im using SIGIO. When there is an IO, `si_fd` is often 0, sometime something else, but not the fd the /dev/* really has. So the object function is called but by another object in the `handler_objects[fd]`

Comment: Since I found the solution for the si_fd-problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19866754/sigio-arriving-for-file-descriptors-i-did-not-set-it-for-and-when-no-io-is-possi.
This method works great. Thanks