# sockfd in SIGINFO struct for SIGIO signal

Tags: c++, sockets, asynchronous, boost, struct

I am removing boost from my application (because I want to get rid of boost while using pre c++ 11) and as part of the same I have run into the following issue.

I have a piece of code which connects, requests and receives data from a remote server asynchronously using boost (async_connect, async_write and async_read calls). I am planning to replace the same with linux native sockets operational in async mode.

For the same I started looking at 
        ioctl(_sockfd, FIOASYNC, &on); 
to set the socket in async mode. 
Next I also set 
        fcntl(_sockfd, F_SETOWN, getpid()); 
to get all sockfd related signals directed to the process creating the socket. 
Handling the SIGIO signal gives access to siginfo_t struct which contains various signal related information.

However I am unable to get the sockfd from the siginfo struct instance received which makes it hard to decipher which sockfd;s SIGIO signal has been caught. si->si_fd doesnt match the _sockfd for which connect is called. **Why does fd in SIGINFO for SIGIO doesnt match the sockfd for which this signal is generated**. Are contents of siginfo even reliable??

Comment: I suggest you to ignore the signal API and to implement your socket handling using select() or poll(), signals do not play well with multithread nor with object oriented design, and if you need async sockets and write your code in C++there is a big chance you will need both.

Comment: Did you set `SA_SIGINFO` when establishing the signal handler using sigaction() ? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19866754/sigio-arriving-for-file-descriptors-i-did-not-set-it-for-and-when-no-io-is-possi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `socket(7)` manpage:

```
Signals
   ...[SIGPIPE para elided]...

   When requested with the FIOSETOWN fcntl(2) or SIOCSPGRP ioctl(2),
   SIGIO is sent when an I/O event occurs.  It is possible to use
   poll(2) or select(2) in the signal handler to find out which socket
   the event occurred on.  An alternative (in Linux 2.2) is to set a
   real-time signal using the F_SETSIG fcntl(2); the handler of the real
   time signal will be called with the file descriptor in the si_fd
   field of its siginfo_t.  See fcntl(2) for more information.

   Under some circumstances (e.g., multiple processes accessing a single
   socket), the condition that caused the SIGIO may have already
   disappeared when the process reacts to the signal.  If this happens,
   the process should wait again because Linux will resend the signal
   later.
```

So,

- *either* use the realtime signal instead with `fcntl(sockfd, F_SETSIG, ...)`,
- *or* use a non-blocking `poll` or `select` in your signal handler to identify the triggering fd,
- *or*, just use normal synchronous multiplexing (`select`/`poll`) in the first place. That's more normal IME, and avoids all the nasty signal-handling issues, but might require restructuring your whole program around an event loop, so ...

Answer (score 0):

How about POSIX aio? I personally never happened to use it, but maybe it is what you are looking for.
https://linux.die.net/man/7/aio

Also, why you don't like `boost::asio`? `boost::thread`, `boost::regexp` and some other things are actually redundant in C++11/14, `boost::filesystem` is redundant in C++17. But Standard Library doesn't contain `asio` analogue. IMHO, it would be better to use ready, tested, portable and widely spread solution than write your own from scratch.

Comment: boost::asio is practically heavy for my use case. Boost IOService queue is too generic and hence has overheads (mutex unlock and lock at every poll_one). Therefore I am thinking to get rid of it.